# Install an APK without lowering the defenses of the device

Tags: android, apk

I am planning a series of "WebApp" for iOS and Android.
For WebApp I mean the kind of application that is opened by browser and install to the desktop (for iOS) with a Tap to the icon to create the shortcut.
The same thing with Android is not as immediate as the iPhone and for the user to medium-low range is not as easy to perform this action quickly.
So the alternative to this would be to create an apk (which for obvious reasons (like the fact that I will realize a hundred of webapp all similar) I can't put in the market). The problem is that installing APK directly, the device prompts to user to lower the defenses of the device .. I would like to avoid this step, so I was wondering, can I build an apk "verified" without loading it on the Market and certified to the point of not lower the defenses of the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I build an apk "verified" without loading it on the Market and certified to the point of not lower the defenses of the device?

Thankfully, you can't. This would be a serious security flaw if it were possible. There's a reason for requiring you to go through channels like Google Play.

Comment: Ok, there is no alternative to this solution?

Comment: @GBleff Not unless you are in control of the device ROM as well. Also, keep in mind that some carrier devices (like some of AT&T) do not allow sideloading.